# Extracting specific terms from Microsoft Word to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Question:
I have coded in VBA the ability to search a Word document for specific terms and extract them into Excel.  The problem I am having is that I would like to begin the start function of the search after the first 50 pages of the Word document for only 5 select terms.  The other terms that I enter, I would like the search and extraction start at the beginning of the document.

For example, if the word was pencil,  I would like the search for the word pencil after 50 pages.  All other terms (i.e. pen) would start the search at the beginning of the document.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please take the time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then come back and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55207803/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post your code, I can't tell exactly what you are doing here, but I'm pretty sure you can take the generic sample below, and incorporate it into your current logic.

```
Sub GetKeyWordPages()
    Dim iPages() As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
    With rng.Find
        .Text = "SearchTerm"
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        Do While .Execute
            ReDim Preserve iPages(p)
            iPages(p) = rng.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
            p = p + 1
        Loop
    End With
    If p > 0 Then
        For p = 0 To UBound(iPages)
            Debug.Print iPages(p)
        Next p
    End If
End Sub
```